# How to clear data from Excel pivot table while keeping connection

Tags: excel, vba, connection, pivot-table, olap-cube

My Excel pivot table connects to external data source (OLAP cube) via windows authentication. I would like to make changes to my pivot table and share/publish the workbook. Since there is row security on the dataset, I would like to keep the table "empty", until connection is refreshed with user's credentials.

Is there a way to save the workbook with no data preloaded to the pivot table from the OLAP cube, while keeping the connection string and preserving all the settings and filters of the pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting your table as an Excel formatted table and set the name of that table to `tblData`.  Then, create the chart but make sure the Chart Data Range is just `=tblData`.  Now you can clear all the data out of the formatted data and the chart will remain in tact.
[image]

Comment: I do not use charts in my workbook. I need to clear a pivot table that is connected to external source (OLAP). I have edited the question so it is clearer.